# Any idea of which mobile web browsers support html5 as of now?

Tags: html, mobile-browser, browser-support

Of all the mobile web browsers out there, more or less which ones support html5 as of now or plan on supporting it?

Comment: The language is called [HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) and all mobile browsers can parse it (= all of them support it).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest going over to http://caniuse.com.  They have a pretty exhaustive list of Html5 and CSS3 browser (desktop and mobile) breakdowns, including future planned support.

Since Html5 is a moving-target, of sorts, you'll find that browsers are at different phases of implementing different *features* of Html5.  It's generally not as black and white as "yes, html5" or "no html5" its more feature-by-feature because that is how Html5 (and CSS3) support is typically being rolled out on browsers.